# Can long-term antidepressant use reduce memory and emotion?

Tags: emotion, memory, depression

Can long-term (~3-4 years) antidepressant use reduce memory and emotion?

Comment: I have edited your question for clarity @Pawan, feel free to roll back if I interpreted your intent incorrectly. If you have any more specific information in mind--different aspects of memory or specific types of emotion--that would help narrow the question down a bit, as well.

Comment: @Krysta no problem.

Comment: @what yes almost like that. if antidepressants do reduce emotion. then there is must be a way to restore emotion.

Comment: @PawanKumarChaurasiya I really have no idea, but I searched for "antidepressant flat emotion" and found some results that may help you with your question: https://www.google.de/search?q=antidepressant+flat+emotion Instead of "flat" you might also try and see if "dull" or "blunt" (with "antidepressant" and "emotion") will lead to better results. Good luck!

Comment: @what sir please if you know a way to restore emotion. then please just let me know. it will really helpful for me. i am not medical expert person. but living without emotion. its so terrible.

Comment: I just met one week ago a psychiatrist. after two days counseling. he said what i am in depression and i need to take more anti-depression medication. very difficult to make decision. again will to take anti-depression medicine. sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I have been victim of depression and I have lost my emotions ... I do recently graduated, got a good job but never felt happy ... I do not cry if something happens bad to me

Comment: Now that the personal references of this question have been removed, it's unclear what you mean by "emotion" or "memory". These are very broad concepts with a lot of dimensions to be measured. What effects have you found in your preliminary research that you'd like clarified?